# How to get full contact from device in to chech box name which can be selectable

Tags: android, mobile, android-contacts

Hello I am new on android development and I am struggling badly with coding...I have to get full contact list of my device in to dynamic growing `checkbox` name which can be selectable 
....
It must be selected already and also which will grow dynamically
I have tried a lot of things already but dont find any answers...and I have to get the selected contacted from it on button press

```
public void fetchContacts() {

        String phoneNumber = null;

         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
                  (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, null);

        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  

        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));

                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                    output.append("\n Name:" + name);

                    // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                    //  String nam[]=new String[]{name};
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nam[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ch.setText(phoneNumber);
                    //  t1.setText(name);
                        ch.setChecked(true);

                    }

                    phoneCursor.close();
```

Comment: What is your current output with this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try this code to fetch my contact

```
try {
            String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

            Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                    null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");


            for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
            {
//              contactWrap.clear();
                try {
                    contactId = 0;
                    String hasPhone = "";
                    display_name = "";
                    phoneNumber = "";

                    c.moveToPosition(i);

                    contactId =  c.getLong(0);
                    display_name = c.getString(1);
                    hasPhone = c.getString(7);

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                        hasPhone = "true";
                    else
                        hasPhone = "false" ;

                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                    {
                        Cursor phones = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            int indexPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);
                            String phoneType =  phones.getString(indexPhoneType);

                            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 

                            String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));


                            contactWrap.add(new ContactsWrapper(contactId, display_name, phoneNumber,lookupKey,false,color_string));
                        }
//                      map.put(contactId, new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>(contactWrap));
                        phones.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

ohk u can take contactID from this cursor or your code now this is my method which will give u contact photo just pass contact ID in it

```
public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
     Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
     Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
          new String[] {Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
     if (cursor == null) {
         return null;
     }
     try {
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
             if (data != null) {
                 return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
             }
         }
     } finally {
         cursor.close();
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Hope this will help u Best of luck dude

Answer (score 0):

you should use content provider of contact
go through this [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/)