# I am trying to export a single contact from the address book to .vcf. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: android

```
package com.example.address_book;import android.app.Activity;import android.content.Intent;import android.database.Cursor;import android.net.Uri;import android.os.Bundle;import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;import android.view.Menu;import android.view.View;import android.view.View.OnClickListener;import android.widget.ImageButton;import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;
String[] num={" "," "};
String number1;

@Overrideprotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

try{ImageButton add_me = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

add_me.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v){

Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Uri.parse("content://contacts"));

pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
});
}catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

int n=0;int n1=0;
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST){
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
Uri stuff = data.getData();Intent in = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, stuff);
in.setType("text/x-vcard");
startActivity(in);
String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(stuff, projection, null, null, null);cursor.moveToFirst();
int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
number1 = cursor.getString(column);
n++;number1 = number1.replace("-" ,"");
for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++){num[i]=number1;
}
}
}
}

@Overridepublic boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);return true;
}
}
```

Comment: see my ans ??????????????????

Comment: This is code which is going to convert all the contact to .vcf format but i want to convert a particular one contact to .vcf format.Plz help me

Comment: then what the prob in this just make .vcf file for that contact only add that new contact in that vcf simple

Comment: Can u plzz send that code

Comment: actually h ere i can only give the idea no enough time to write whole code here because it will take a lot of time and need also debug ans testing so u start urself dude and take help of any senior in ur place

Comment: Can u plzz tell me is there any wrong in my code...

Comment: your code is not in well format so its not readable dude

Answer (score -1):

Try with this dude it will open your contact jusr pass contactId in this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //pass your contact id 
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactId));
    intent.setData(uri);
    mcntxt.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how to add contact id

Comment: have u able to get contact id from device then just pass with this my method that

Comment: how to get contact id from device

Comment: see my ans dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627829/how-to-get-full-contact-from-device-in-to-chech-box-name-which-can-be-selectable/22627872#22627872